# Building out a van

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, volume

I need insulation for my van. 110' x 69 x 5'11 high. How much insulation is needed? It will be between 1/2" thick. I know it's optimization but that's where I stop! I would want the maximum of the optimization...I think.

Comment: Do you envision that the van is approximately a [rectangular cuboid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle) with each surface covered in insulation?

Comment: Yes...I do. I am totally okay with having extra. But JUST the interior surface, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really the right website for these kinds of questions - which is why your question is attracting downvotes - but, since I find the question mathematically interesting, I've given it an upvote and I'll answer your question.

**Assumptions.** Assume your van is an $a \times b \times c$ rectangular cuboid. Assume your insulation is going to be $k$ units-of-length thick.

**Approximate value.** The surface area of your van is $2bc+2ac+2ab,$ so you'll need approximately $$2k(bc+ac+ab)$$ worth of insulation. For example, suppose $a=b=c=10$ and $k=1$. Then the approximate formula gives: $$2 \cdot 1 \cdot (100+100+100) = 600$$

But this actually overestimates the amount of insulation you'll need, because we're double and triple counting in places.

**Exact value.** The exact formula seems to be:

$$2k(bc+ac+ab - 2k(a+b+c)+4k^2)$$

For example, suppose $a=b=c=10$ and $k=1$. Then the exact formula gives:

$$2 \cdot 1 \cdot (100+100+100-2(10+10+10)+4\cdot 1^2) = 488$$

Just replace $a,b,c$ and $k$ with your own numbers in your preferred units to solve the specific problem you're having.

Comment: I think that my approach is wrong and I deleted my answer.

Comment: This is just $a\times b\times c-(a-2k)\times(b-2k)\times(c-2k)$, isn't it? The volume of the van minus the volume not occupied by insulation.